# PHP JavaScript Facebook SDK Codeigniter setting app permissions

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok, I have codeigniter as my MVC, and I have the stock facebook sdk 3.x whatever the latest is at this time, and I am trying to figure out how to add more than just "basic info" to my app permission when the user first authenticates. I am building this from scratch essentially, originally I had tried Elliot Haughin's library, but for one reason or another it started to fail me, so I figure rather than 3rd party build my own deal from scratch and have a better understanding of whats going on where and when.

Problem is though with Elliots library he had it setup to just pretty much type out an array of the settings you wanted in one file, and then it would be passed on to something else, I assume the login for a user when the app has yet to be apporved by the user.

What i want to do is recreate that idea, or at least know where I should include it so I can get my outside the basic info needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the permissions in the `getLoginUrl` function as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/):

```
$params = array( 
             'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
             'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
         );
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

If you want to load the permissions from a configuration file you can do this:

```
'scope' => $this->config->item('app_permissions'),
```

EDIT:

In JS SDK you have two options depending on the implementation of the login button:

a.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
       // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'read_stream, friends_likes'});
```

b.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="read_stream, friends_likes" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

Comment: now I am mix matching javascript with php in this case, is this something I would want to pass to the javascript via php where the javascript creates the login button?